# Unable to update below apt

Tags: apt, grub2, upgrade

```
root@vishal-Ubuntu:~# apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
gnome-remote-desktop/jammy-updates 42.7-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.3-0ubuntu1]  
python3-software-properties/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.5 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.2]  
software-properties-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.5 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.2]  
software-properties-gtk/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.5 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.2]
ubuntu-advantage-tools/jammy-updates 27.13.3~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 27.9~22.04.1]  
update-notifier-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 3.192.54.5 all [upgradable from: 3.192.54]  
update-notifier/jammy-updates 3.192.54.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.192.54]
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear; are you just asking what the command for `apt full-upgrade` is? or what is your actual issue.

Comment: Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community. Your question as written is unclear. Can you please provide some additional context around what it is that you're doing and what you hope to achieve? This will help us better address your issue.